# Python Code to iteratively subtract until zero

Tags: python

New guy problems.
I'm a Roleplaying game geek attempting to make a character builder.  There are four attributes (Strength Agility Wits and Empathy).  I'm attempting to assign numbers to each of these attributes randomly BUT you only get eight (8) total points to work with so you have to iteratively subtract them as their numbers are assigned.  Here was my lame attempt.  Didn't work.  Do i need a For loop somewhere?

```
import random

some_number = random.randint(1,8)
num_one = 8 - random.randint(1,some_number)
num_two = num_one - (random.randint(1,num_one))
num_three = num_two - (random.randint(1,num_two))
num_four = num_three - (random.randint(1,num_three))


print(num_one)
print(num_two)
print(num_three)
print(num_four)
```

Comment: Say I use all points on `num_one`, should the rest be 0's? What about if there's points left over after `num_three`, should all remaining points go to `num_four`?

Comment: I recommend checking out some basic OOP, or at the very least using a dictionary to store your stats by name, e.g.: `{'Strength': 4, 'Agility': 1, 'Wits': 2, 'Empathy': 1}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easier route is to distribute the 8 points randomly among the 4 stats:

```py
import random

stats = [0,0,0,0]

for i in range(8):
    stats[random.randrange(4)] += 1

print(stats)
```

A few runs:

```
[2, 3, 0, 3]
[1, 1, 4, 2]
[0, 2, 2, 4]
[2, 2, 2, 2]
[3, 1, 1, 3]
[0, 3, 4, 1]
[1, 2, 5, 0]
[4, 2, 2, 0]
[2, 3, 2, 1]
[3, 1, 3, 1]
```

If you want to get fancy with a class:

```py
import random

class Player:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        stats = [0,0,0,0]
        for i in range(8):
            stats[random.randrange(4)] += 1
        self.str, self.agi, self.wit, self.emp = stats

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Player(name={self.name!r}, ST={self.str}, AG={self.agi}, WT={self.wit}, EM={self.emp})'

players = [Player(name) for name in ('Mark','Joe')]
print(players)
```

A few runs:

```
[Player(name='Mark', ST=2, AG=3, WT=0, EM=3), Player(name='Joe', ST=2, AG=3, WT=0, EM=3)]
[Player(name='Mark', ST=1, AG=1, WT=4, EM=2), Player(name='Joe', ST=0, AG=2, WT=2, EM=4)]
[Player(name='Mark', ST=5, AG=1, WT=0, EM=2), Player(name='Joe', ST=3, AG=2, WT=2, EM=1)]
[Player(name='Mark', ST=3, AG=2, WT=3, EM=0), Player(name='Joe', ST=3, AG=3, WT=1, EM=1)]
[Player(name='Mark', ST=4, AG=2, WT=2, EM=0), Player(name='Joe', ST=3, AG=0, WT=2, EM=3)]
```

Comment: That is a really clever solution. I'd never thought of using `randrange` that way

Comment: Could this be adapted to a dictionary like: `{'Strength': 0, 'Agility': 0, 'Wits': 0, 'Empathy': 0}`?

Comment: @BeRT2me yes, just randomly select a key instead of an index.

Comment: @BeRT2me Start with your dictionary and use `random.choice(['Strength','Agility','Wits','Empathy'])` instead.

Comment: Ye, I was writing one up to try for myself that does `random.choice(list(stats))` where `stats` is my dictionary as noted above~

Comment: Really appreciated everyone's posts here.  One question though, what is the value of 4 have to do with the logic of the code "random.randrange(4)"?

Comment: @Dirtymike It works like the function `range()` as far as parameters.  It picks a number from 0-3.  See the documentation: [randrange()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange)

Comment: @MarkTolonen i'm really surprised but i understand exactly what you're talking about now! thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There are a few good ways to go about this, but personally I'd use a list and a for loop.

This code starts off with all stats set to 0, and then loops 8 times, each time increasing a point for a random stat. After this code runs, `stats[0]` represents Strength, `stats[1]` represents Agility, etc.

```py
import random
points = 8
stats = [0, 0, 0, 0]
for _ in range(points):
    stats[random.randint(0,len(stats)-1)] += 1
print(stats)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to use a loop:

```
import random

total_points = 8
remaining = total_points

values = []
for i in range(3):
    value = remaining - random.randint(1, remaining)
    remaining = remaining - value
    values.append(value)
values.append(remaining)
```

This works by declaring a value called `remaining` that we'll use to hold the number of points that can still be assigned. Then, for each iteration of the loop, we create a new value by subtracting a random number from `remaining`. We then reassign `remaining` with the value we calculated so we can ensure that it decreases with each successive calculation. Finally, we add the value we calculated to a list. At the end you'll have a list of four randomized values.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the accepted answer, you could even make a way to create random Players:

```
import random

random_name_list = ['Joe', 'Bob', 'Sam', 'Sally', 'Jerry', 'George', 'Tom']

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, pts=8):
        self.name = name
        stats = [0,0,0,0]
        for i in range(pts):
            stats[random.randrange(4)] += 1
        self.str, self.agi, self.wit, self.emp = stats
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Player(name={self.name!r}, ST={self.str}, AG={self.agi}, WT={self.wit}, EM={self.emp})'
    @classmethod
    def random_player(cls):
        return Player(random.choice(random_name_list))

players = []
for _ in range(5):
    players.append(Player.random_player())

print(players)
```

Output:

```
[Player(name='Sam', ST=0, AG=1, WT=3, EM=4), 
Player(name='Tom', ST=3, AG=4, WT=0, EM=1), 
Player(name='Sam', ST=3, AG=3, WT=0, EM=2), 
Player(name='Joe', ST=2, AG=2, WT=1, EM=3), 
Player(name='Tom', ST=1, AG=1, WT=3, EM=3)]
```